# name for a degree-like invariant of a power series over a commutative ring

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, power-series

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $f \in R[\![X]\!]$ be a formal power series.  Sometimes (and for example, this will always be possible if $R$ is Noetherian), one may write $f$ in the form $$
f = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i u_i X^i,
$$ where $a_i \in R$ and $u_i$ is a *unit* in $R[\![X]\!]$.  I call the smallest such $n$ for which such an expression is possible the *pseudodegree* of $f$.

At least, that's what I and a coauthor called it in a recent preprint.  It seemed reasonable, since if one makes the same definition in the polynomial ring $R[X]$, this concept coincides with the usual notion of the *degree* of a polynomial, at least when $R$ is reduced.  Also, like the degree of a polynomial, the pseudodegree of $f$ is at least as big as one less than the minimal number of generators of the ideal of $R$ that is generated by the coefficients of $f$.

But this must have a name somewhere, right? Can anyone point to an article, book, preprint or the like where this concept has been used?  What else can be said about pseudodegree?

Comment: A trivial comment. Pseudodegree may not coincide with the usual degree in polynomial rings if the base ring had nilpotents.

Comment: Oh, good point; I'll make the corresponding edit.

Comment: Am I wrong that this is just looking at the filtration of $R[[x]]$ by powers of the ideal $I=\langle X\rangle$?  It sure looks to me like your "elements of pseudo degree $n$" are the just the elements of $I^n\setminus I^{n+1}$, which is what I would call them.

Comment: @BenWebster: No, I don't think that's it. For instance, if $R=\mathbb Z$ and $f=3X+2X^2$, then $f$ is in $I \setminus I^2$, but $f$ has pseudodegree $2$ (I think).  Your attempted characterization may be right when $R$ is local, but not otherwise.

Comment: I see.  I figured there was something I was missing.

Comment: @BenWebster For what it's worth, there is a name for the concept you outlined.  When $I=\langle X \rangle$ in $R[\![X]\!]$, then the elements of $I^n \setminus I^{n+1}$ are the power series of *order* $n$.  This is indeed a common substitute in power series extensions for the notion of degree (e.g. in the proof of the power series version of the Hilbert Basis Theorem), so it makes sense that you would think of it.  In the context of the preprint I allude to above, though, order wasn't a useful notion.  We needed pseudodegree.

Comment: If $f=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i X^i$, and $I_n=(a_0,\dots,a_n)$, then this is the $n$ at which the increasing sequence of ideals $I_n$ stabilizes, right?

Comment: Indeed.  We noted this in our preprint, and it was essentially why we defined the notion in the first place.

Comment: Anyone else? The bounty is almost expired..

Comment: Question: is the psuedo degree multiplicative? is there a counter-example?

Comment: I'm guessing the preprint was this one: http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1100